# How could a dummy Browser.msgBox call affect output in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that moves data from one sheet to another and as part of this must insert the appropriate number of rows into the second sheet to account for the data from the first sheet. I'm running into an issue where, for reasons I don't quite understand, the data is duplicated in the second sheet, e.g. if 94 rows are in the original sheet, the second contains these 94 rows then an additional 94 rows right below with the exact same data. My code is:

```
function moveToEntrySheet(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rawRow = 2;

  var entrySheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var rawSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var entryRow = 4;
  var numEntries = rawSheet.getLastRow() - 1;
  if (numEntries <= 0){
    return;
  }
  Browser.msgBox(numEntries);
  entrySheet.insertRowsBefore(entryRow, numEntries);
  Browser.msgBox(numEntries);
  var entryRange = entrySheet.getRange(4, 2, numEntries, 6);
  var vals = rawSheet.getRange(2, 1, numEntries, 6).getValues();
  Browser.msgBox(numEntries);
  entryRange.setValues(vals);
}
```

To try and debug this I put calls to Browser.msgBox() in my code to make sure that numEntries is the expected number (94), which it does appear to be at each of the 3 points that I put the call in. The weird thing is that when I run this function with the calls to msgBox() included, the entries are only pulled to the other sheet once. If I keep the first call in it works the same, and if I keep the second or third call in double the number of rows that should be inserted are inserted but the data isn't copied itself, essentially giving n empty rows in the sheet, where n is the number of rows of data in sheet 1. How could calls to Browser.msgBox() affect the copy in this way, and how can I avoid the copy from duplicating? Thanks!

Comment: I removed all of the msgboxes and it runs for me. Try shutting down you browser and bringing it back up.

Comment: So it turns out it was something else completely. I'd been having issues where my script would run for more than 30 seconds, therefore getting cutoff as this is called from onEdit() which is limited to 30 seconds. To get around this I installed an onEdit trigger that called onEdit, assuming it would just overwrite the simple trigger. Turns out I was wrong and this was causing onEdit to get called twice, once by the simple trigger and once by the installed trigger